# How do I force any subclasses of my class to always call a parent's implementation method they are overriding?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, overriding

Let's say I have a class, which implements a method (addThings()). It serves as a foundation of a tree of subclasses:

```
ParentClass {
    protected void addThings() {
        map.add(thing1);
        map.add(thing2);
    }
}
```

Now, let's say we implement a child class (which has Thing 3 as well) and Thing 3 also needs to be added **on top of Thing 1 and Thing 2**.

The obvious Java solution seems to be to have the child's class's implementation of the method call the super's method:

```
ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    protected void addThings() {
        super.addThings();
        map.add(thing3);
    }
}
```

**The problem is that whoever implements the subclass may very well forget to do that, and have a bug**:

```
ChildClassBad extends ParentClass {
    protected void addThings() {
        // BUG!!! Forgot to call super.addThings(); !!!
        map.add(thing3); 
    }
}
```

Is there a way in Java to **force** any of the extending child (and grandchild) classes to always call a parent's method if they override it? (similar to how making a method abstract always forces them to implement it).

- Please note that I need the solution to be propagatable down the inheritance tree.

  In other words, if someone implements GrandChildClass which needs to add Thing4, they would suffer from the same bug possibility relative to ChildClass.

  This means that the simple fix (applicable when you only have 1 level of inheritance) of having separate "addParentThings()" in ParentClass and then calling both addParentThings() and child-overridable empty addThings() is insufficient (*because the grandchild has to override non-empty addThings*).

Comment: As far as I know, you cannot reinforce the call to a super-method. Can you give us more details as to why you want to use such a mechanism? Maybe you have an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @Turing85 - I am implementing a parent class that will be there for a while and is likely to get subclassed a lot. I spotted an **obvious** likely bug any subclass implementor will be subject to, and I want a Java-compiler-based solution to this problem (as opposed to "write a comment telling people to do that and hope that they read the comment")

Comment: I get your general idea, but I think you could prevent the problem on another way. In the given example, you could reinforce your condition through the constructor, but I don't think that your case is that simple.

Comment: @Turing85 - the method has to be called a number of times on an object, so a constructor is, unfortunately, not viable approach (my coworker already suggested that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to make your `doStuff`-Methods static for each class, which extends your `ParentClass` and give your `ParentClass` a `final public void doAllStuff()`-Method, you can solve the problem with Reflection:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        A a = new C();
        a.doAllStuff();
    }
}

class A
{
    protected List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static void doStuff(A a)
    {
        a.list.add("I am A");
    }

    final public void doAllStuff()
    {
        List<Class<?>> list = new ArrayList<Class<?>>();
        Class<?> clazz = this.getClass();
        while (A.class.getSuperclass() != clazz)
        {
            list.add(clazz);
            clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
        }
        System.out.println(list);
        for (Class<?> myClass : list)
        {
            try
            {
                Method method = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("doStuff"
                                                          , myClass);
                // Method is private? Make it accessible anyway.
                method.setAccessible(true);
                method.invoke(this, this);
            }
            catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
            {
                // Method not found, continue with next class.
                continue;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(this.list);
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static void doStuff(B b)
    {
        b.list.add("I am B");
    }
}

class C extends B {}
```

If you need to only call attributes, you can use `getDeclaredField`, the fields may not be `static` in this case.

Comment: So far, this is the best approach of all answers. The only minor downsides so far is that (1) it is static-restricted (and frankly, I don't see why it can't be extended to object methods just as easily? You can get the class of underlying caller object by using `getClass()`); (2) It opens up to a reverse bug, where an implementor of class B accidentally adds a call to super.doStuff() in his implementation where they shouldn't. I think this one also can be worked around.

Comment: I'm delaying accepting the answer due to the downsides, but will most likely accept this answer unless something better is proposed.

Comment: @DVK the problem with object-methods is the dynamic binding: calling `doStuff` of an object of type `B` must always result in a call to `B.doStuff()` (such is the nature of dynamic binding). I canceled out "accidentally" calling of `doStuff`-methods by setting them private. This way, they are only visible within the class and cannot be accessed from the outside. Another possible approach is the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), but for this, you would have to wrap each object within a new object.

Comment: Looks like a pain to track down problems at runtime.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe try having a final method that calls another overridable method?

```
class ParentClass {

    public final void doStuff() {
        // Do stuff
        onPostDoStuff();
    }

    protected void onPostDoStuff() {
        // Override this!
    }
}
```

And then in the child class:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

    @Override
    protected void onPostDoStuff() {
        // Do extra stuff
    }
}
```

You could even make the `onPostDoStuff()` method abstract, so children *have* to override it.

Comment: This seems to **NOT AT ALL** help with grandchild class overriding child class's method? (you seem to merely be taking the solution  I explicitly rejected in the second half of my post and slapping a "final" on it despite that not being of any help)

Comment: I think this remains the best approach. If you need to apply it further for a grand child class, make `onPostDoStuff()` `final` and apply the same principle again.

Comment: @DidierL - and if I need a grandgrandchild, make yet another method??? That seems incredibly awful as an approach. Moreover, **it doesn't answer the question at all** as the question very explicitly rejected this method as inappropriate

Answer (score 1):

The following approach enforces invocation of the superclass' setup method. The downside, or likely bug in subclasses, is that implementers might forget to provide a suitable constructor for providing an extension to the setup method. This means that child couldn't be extended by a grandchild.

Its also ugly because subclasses can't put subclass-specific setup in their extensions; they have to accept `Parent` as a parameter.

Overall, the awkwardness difficulties here suggest that enforcement is better done, if at all, in a static analyzer, rather than `javac`.

```
public class Parent
{

  private final Consumer<Parent> setup;

  protected final Collection<Object> x = new ArrayList<>();

  public Parent()
  {
    setup = Parent::setupImpl;
  }

  protected Parent(Consumer<Parent> extension)
  {
    setup = ((Consumer<Parent>) Parent::setupImpl).andThen(extension);
  }

  public final void setup()
  {
    setup.accept(this);
  }

  private static void setupImpl(Parent it)
  {
    it.x.add("thing1");
    it.x.add("thing2");
  }

}

public class Child
  extends Parent
{

  public Child()
  {
    super(Child::setupImpl);
  }

  protected Child(Consumer<Parent> extension)
  {
    super(((Consumer<Parent>) Child::setupImpl).andThen(extension));
  }

  private static void setupImpl(Parent it)
  {
    it.x.add("thing3");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different approach for solving your problem, as in one of the comments to the selected answer says, you can use the decorator pattern (it is a little different from a traditional decorator, adapted to this problem), it is a cleaner solution in my opinion. I added 2 classes that add thing 3 and thing 4 to show the usage.

```
public interface ThingAdder {
  void addThings();
}

public abstract class AbstractAdder implements ThingAdder {
  protected List<String> map = new ArrayList<>(); // or your map impl
}

public class DefaultAdderDecorator implements ThingAdder {
  AbstractAdder decoratedThingAdder;

  public DefaultAdderDecorator(AbstractAdder decoratedThingAdder) {
    this.decoratedThingAdder = decoratedThingAdder;
  }

  @Override
  public void addThings() {
      decoratedThingAdder.map.add("thing 1");
      decoratedThingAdder.map.add("thing 2");
      decoratedThingAdder.addThings();
  }
}

public class Thing3Adder extends AbstractAdder {
  @Override
  public void addThings() {
    map.add("thing 3");
  }
}

public class Thing4Adder extends AbstractAdder {
  @Override
  public void addThings() {
    map.add("thing 4");
  }
}

public class AdderApp {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thing3Adder thing3Adder = new Thing3Adder();
    Thing4Adder thing4Adder = new Thing4Adder();
    ThingAdder decoratedAdder = new DefaultAdderDecorator(thing3Adder);

    decoratedAdder.addThings();
    System.out.println("Decorated Thing3Adder map:"+thing3Adder.map);

    decoratedAdder = new DefaultAdderDecorator(thing4Adder);

    decoratedAdder.addThings();
    System.out.println("Decorated Thing4Adder map:"+thing4Adder.map);
  }
}
```

After running AdderApp this is printed:

```
Decorated Thing3Adder map:[thing 1, thing 2, thing 3]
Decorated Thing4Adder map:[thing 1, thing 2, thing 4]
```

The idea behind the decorator pattern is to augment existing functionality, in this case we are augmenting the addThings method by using a default decoration that adds thing 1 and thing 2 before calling the decorated object own addThings method, then whenever it is needed to have a new adder which requires the default values to be inserted first, the developer will just create a new ThingXAdder that extends the AbstractAdder.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of anything that would satisfy your condition of still being enforceable in future subclasses.

The Android sdk has the "super has not been called" exceptions in many of their core lifecycle methods, but it is strictly single level inheritance.